# Glitch in the chatroom

Tags: discussion, bug

So there is a bug in the chatroom.

Here's the glitch in simple ways.

I have currently 184 Rep. and the chatroom oddly thinks that i have 200 Rep.

Does any users or mod want to deny this?

EDIT: I am stupid. Thanks @takkat for explaining this to me. No further discussions are needed.

Comment: Your rep sum can be seen here: http://stackexchange.com/users/8198340/%c6%8ep%e1%b4%89%ca%87%ca%8exd?tab=accounts